# How do I make a batch web browser?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch web browser for my own mini os. I have tried using the type command but that won't work. How do I embed websites into batch files?
Here is what I have so far:

```
    @echo off
    set /p website=What site do you want to read?
    type %website%
    pause
```

Comment: Looks like you're almost done

Comment: by batch web browser you mean a webpage loader/parser/renderer... with a batch file? And what's your own mini OS? Batch file is a DOS/Windows format so who knows what are your mini OS's batch file format is?

Comment: The "Be Nice" rule prevents me from expressing my opinions about this idea, but I _suppose_ you could package wget or curl with your script, download the web page, and then `type` the HTML file. But if you're bundling third-party software with your script, you might as well just include [Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/).

Comment: As @SomethingDark said, I believe a curl should works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what you are trying to do, also, by mini os i'm guessing you mean a set of programs in windows that will have some core functions that an os would. In addition, if you wanted to write a web browser for your mini os, I really, really don't think batch is the right choice. If you wanted to create your own browser you should use python as it is relatively easy to program in sockets, which would allow you to create custom tcp/ip packets that could gather data from a server. This isn't the easiest thing to do, so I would suggest just using a browser with a command line interface. Coding in sockets to batch would be extremely difficult, and I'm not sure if it's even possible without any extra programs. From what I can read on your batch program, you could just use start chrome.exe and then use executable nircmd, available on the interwebs, to type a specific website, because the type command doesn't actually send the keystrokes. In terms of creating web browsers there are tons of tutorials on the internet, so good luck coding.

Comment: Thankyou. And by mini os that's what I mean but it is mostly based in one file like it has it's own desktop.